# Thread connection Postgresql db dont work

Tags: android, database, multithreading, postgresql, android-asynctask

my problem is that I want connect to a db of Postgresql in android, and I see that I need do with a thread, I make this thread in a private class under main class, but dont work, the "Toast" always show "Vacío". What I do bad? :/

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnEntrar;
    EditText etUsuario;
    EditText etPass;

    public static String login = "Vacío";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEntrar);
        etUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsuario);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);

        btnEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usuario = etUsuario.getText().toString();
                String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
                new ConnUsers(usuario, pass).execute();


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /*if(login){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IncidenciasActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Acceso es TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Acceso es FALSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } */
            }
        });
    }

    private class ConnUsers extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

        private static final String DB_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        private static final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx/xxx";
        private static final String user = "xxx";
        private static final String password = "xxx";

        private String usuario;
        private String pass;

        public ConnUsers(String usuario, String pass){
            this.usuario = usuario;
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String acceso = "doInBackground";

            try{
                Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '" + usuario +"'");

                if(rs.next()!=false){
                    if(Funciones.md5(pass).equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("password"))){

                        int id = rs.getInt("id");

                        acceso = "Todo correcto";
                    }
                    else{
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Password incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        acceso = "Falla la pass";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Usuario incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    acceso = "Falla el usuario";
                }

                rs.close();
                st.close();
                connection.close();

            }catch(SQLException e){
                cancel(true);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return acceso;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            MainActivity.login = s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: That's your real code or just a demo? I'm saying that because of yor database connection user and password = 'xxx' and your connectionString = jdbc:postgresql://xxx/xxxx

Comment: I change the real ip, user and pass for "xxx" , in real code is all right

Comment: Okey! What happen if you put the toast in the onPostExecute()?, that method is useful when you want to manipulate User Interface when doInBackground() finish. Also try to print "acceso" making the variable as class variable.

Comment: Put "Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());" to your catcher and we will be see what is your main problem.

Comment: If I try to put the toast in the onPostExecute() say that I cant use a "context" in this class :/ I will put Logs for see, and say here

Comment: Logs of "Error": 05-07 14:27:07.797 1187-1187/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13) ////////

HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7012a20, tid 1255  ///////   E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000  /////// E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)  and more... :/

Comment: You can make a context variable in AsynkTask and you can pass the context of your activity trough AsynkTask constructor and reference it to AynkTask class. Something like : Context ctx; and in the constructor : public connUsers(String usuario, String pass, Context ctx){ this.ctx = ctx; ...}

Comment: Yes but with Toast do error :/ And I dont need Context in AsyncTask, just return a String for example from AsyncTask Class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your connection can't access to PostgreSQL server **for security**. İt's mean your database working just **Localhost.** Because some servers block directly connection in general.
İf your problem is it, You should use **WebService.** Like that

[image]

Comment: I think that I did connect a time trying, but now when I want send "acceso" to the main, dont work :/